# If $x^y + y^x = 84$ and $x>3$, find the value of $x$ and $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do we go about this questions?

I see that taking log on both sides is not an option since the LHS consists of a sum and not a product.

I tried differentiating it but without any boundary conditions I fail to see any possible solutions.

Can someone guide me on how to tackle this question?

Comment: $x,y$ integers, or any reals?

Comment: not specified. I'd assume them to be integers.

Comment: By the way, the above expression is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  There aren't many choices for $y$.  It can only be $1,2,$ or $3,$ because if it is $4$ or greater $x^y \gt 84$  So try each of them in turn and see what you find.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: That's not quite true. If $x$ is 1 $y$ can be as large as $83$ (which actually gives a solution).

Comment: @ElmarZander:  but we were given $x \gt 3$.  Otherwise, you are correct

Comment: @RossMillikan Oops, you're right. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3):

Note if $y=1$ then $f(x,1) = x+1$ so let $x = 83$.

Comment: This is a solution, but there might be more.

Comment: @RossMillikan after your answer, made no sense to rewrite the same thing -- there aren't any more :)

Answer (score 1):

(1,83) and (83,1) seem to be the only answers.

```
In [1]: for x in range(1,84):
   ...:     for y in range(1,84):
   ...:         if x**y + y**x == 84: 
   ...:             print (x,y)
   ...:             
(1, 83)
(83, 1)
```

(Don't know whether python scripts are allowed to prove things on MSE, though)

Comment: They are a fine approach if the problem is susceptible to exhaustion, as it is here.